# Spring MVC appending context path to form action

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, spring-mvc

Was running same code fine under Spring 3.1.  Just upgraded to 3.2 and now the following issue occurs:

```
<form:form id="customerLoginForm" commandName="customerLoginForm" action="/login" name="">
```

under 3.1 would generate the following HTML:

```
<form id="customerLoginForm" action="/login" method="post">
```

now generates:

```
<form id="customerLoginForm" action="/webapp/login" method="post">
```

where "webapp" is the context path in Websphere of our webapp.

In the example above, the GET request to /login is successful but returns the improper form action="/webapp/login" (the form submits a POST back to the same URL).  So when the form is submitted I get a 404 bad URL error.

Did something change in 3.2?  Is there somewhere to tell Spring to ignore the context path?  I could go back change all absolute paths to relative paths (e.g., "login" instead of "/login") but I'd prefer not to since there are 20+ forms in my webapp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry it's not a bug, it's a new feature. Please see this jira: [Form tag should prepend the contextPath and servletPath if not present](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8684)

Which apparently got rolled back on 3.2.3. So you might see your code behavior return to normal just by upgrading to latest version

Comment: This was definitely it.  Upgraded from 3.2.2 to 3.2.3 and the context path no longer was prepended to the form tag's action.