# how to load image from java project's resource/images folder?

Tags: java, spring, maven, load, classpath

I am developing a shopping cart in Sprng MVC from where seller can upload products image with its description. I am able to upload images to `webapp/resources/images` folder. now I have to load all these images to dashboard page (home page) when any user open my site. I am not able to load these images from this location.

In my jsp I am writing final code like this:

```
<img src="resources/images/product1.jpg"/>
```

how can I add this folder to classpath so it'll be available. I am using Spring MVC and MAVEN.

Please let me know how to achieve this.

Comment: can you please share image upload to resource folder code.??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to fix this problem:
Added the following resources declaration to Spring configuration

```
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

and in jsp

```
<img src="<c:url value="/resources/images/product1.jpg" />" alt="" />
```

Thanks guys for your all help, your direction really helped me to get the answer for this problem.

Comment: I am able to fix this problem:
Added the following resources declaration to Spring configuration



<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />



and in jsp


<img src="<c:url value="/resources/images/product1.jpg" />" alt="" />



Thanks guys for your all help, your direction really helped me to get the answer for this problem.

Answer (score 3):

With [Expression Language (EL)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html) in JSP:

```
<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/images/product1.jpg"/>
```

Comment: +1 This should append the `/webapp/` automatically and solve OP's problem.

Comment: ${pageContext.request.contextPath} is giving me my project folder's name and url is forming /myShoppingCart/resources/images/product1.jpg and image is not coming up

Comment: can you please share image upload to resource folder code.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you have uploaded your images to a separate folder on your server and you want to include the folder in the classpath to retrieve and show the images on your JSP.

In Spring MVC, you can force the use of the absolute path (relative to the root of the system) by prefixing *'file:'* with the URL resource:

```
// actual context type doesn't matter, the Resource will always be UrlResource`
ctx.getResource("file:/root/webapp/resources/images");
```

or

```
// force this FileSystemXmlApplicationContext to load its definition via a UrlResource`
ApplicationContext ctx =
        new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("file:/root/webapp/resources/images");`
```

This is one way of adding your image directory by specifying the absolute URL.

If you have your image directory relative to your current directory and want to add to your class path, then the following ways will work:

```
ApplicationContext ctx =
    new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("resources/images");
```

This works relative to the current working directory.The images will be loaded from a filesystem location, in this case relative to the current working directory. so, we have added the directory to classpath. In the same way, you can make the classpath configuration in your XML as well.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**"
               location="classpath:resources/images"
               cache-period="10000" />
```

or

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**"
               location="file:/root/webapp/resources/images"
               cache-period="10000" />
```

we will be able to retrieve the images now in your JSP as follows

```
<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/images/user.jpg"/>
```

The above EL `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` ensures that the Context is always prepended.

Note: In Spring 3.2.2, [the Context path is prepended automatically if not present.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733690/spring-mvc-appending-context-path-to-form-action)