# Spring wrong link location

Tags: java, spring

I have a web app. My controller looks like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public class MainController {    

   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String index() {
      return "index";
   }

   @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public String add(ModelMap model, User user) {
      userService.create(user);
      model.addAttribute("message", "User successfully created.");
      return "index";
   }
}
```

And I have a form like:

```
<form:form method="POST" action="/add" commandName="user">
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>client</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>client</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/client-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

My application is accessed via link: `http://localhost:8080/Client`
But when I submit form it submits to `http://localhost:8080/add` when it should be `http://localhost:8080/Client/add`
I figured, that i could use `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` before every link, but is there any other way?

Comment: Oh, I think I got your point :)

Comment: Oops, was in a hurry. Added web.xml.

Comment: This is app deplyed in tomcat? What is WAR name?

Comment: WAR name is `Client.war`

Comment: You need to read application context dynamically (`Client`), because when you deploy your app with different name, then static link will not work.

Comment: What is your spring version

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41663/discussion-between-mariuszs-and-qiguar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<form:form method="POST" action="${requestContext.pathToServlet}/add" commandName="user">
```

Read more:

- https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8863
- https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8684

Related questions:

- [Spring MVC appending context path to form action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733690/spring-mvc-appending-context-path-to-form-action)
- [Spring MVC: Url path appending when posting the form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18631147/spring-mvc-url-path-appending-when-posting-the-form)

Comment: Also works. It seems that in spring 3.2.3(I'm using) this option was removed, instead they made `servletRelativeAction` tag, but when i set it to true still getting error, but with `${requestContext.pathToServlet}` works fine. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Maybe `servletRelativeAction` is for [portlets only](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/399f887128f2dc0dcaadb7b7df2826ce0b9dcf79)? I think `${requestContext.pathToServlet}` is recomended way to do this.

Comment: I see, but how does requestContext work if it was rolled back? Or am I missing something?

Comment: `requestContext` was not rolled back. Rolled back was automate prepending `contextPath` to action url. This was added in 3.2.2 and reverted in 3.2.3 :)

Comment: Now i get it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`c:url`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/url.html) to automatically prepend the context root to your URL.

```
<c:url var="formUrl" value="/add" />
<form:form method="POST" action="${formUrl}" commandName="user">
```

Comment: Yeah, it works, but I will have to do this for every link i have. Is there another way? Also added `web.xml` if it helps.